# IE9 white flash on page change

Tags: html, css, meteor, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to find a solution of the IE white flash in a meteor app.
The website is [this one](http://beta.veganwall.com) (note that it's in closed beta).

IE9 gives a very bad user experience, and while I don't think it will ever be as good as with more modern browser, I really think some issues should be resolved.
And I think that the white flash on page change it's the worst one.
Basically for every action that changes the url, the page redraws itself and flashes white for a few milliseconds.

I've read other topics and tried to apply some of the suggest fixed, but nothing worked.
I've tried to insert

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Page-Exit" CONTENT="BlendTrans(Duration=0.0)">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Page-Enter" CONTENT="BlendTrans(Duration=0.0)">
```

But I think it does nothing on IE9 or in this case.
I also tried to set the background of html and body to dark gray, it did nothing.
I'm actually not sure what else should I try and if this is a common issue when building website with realtime, modern frameworks.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I also found [this issue](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/14) in iron-router, and it seems that IE<10 trigger a full page refresh every time, and probably that's the main cause of what I'm seeing, because Meteor needs a bit of time to load itself, thus leaving the page blank while it's doing it's magic.

Comment: There is a similar post to this [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301293/images-flash-white-in-internet-explorer-9-while-navigating)

Comment: It's not similar, the site linked in that question is pretty different, the answers do not apply to my case and it doesn't flash anymore in IE9 (and the author didn't write how it finally managed to resolve the issue).   
I've already searched with on stackoverflow and with google, otherwise I would not have opened a new question.

Answer (score 0):

this meta tags

```html
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Page-Exit" CONTENT="BlendTrans(Duration=0.0)">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Page-Enter" CONTENT="BlendTrans(Duration=0.0)">
```

[not supported](http://forums.asp.net/t/1711712.aspx?blendTrans%20meta%20tag%20seems%20to%20not%20work%20in%20IE%209) in IE9.

As solution for you example you can use compatibility with IE8
you can add

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but it still didn't fix the major issue.
I'm starting to think it's [this issue related to iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/14) and there's very little to do.